# Prestashop - Retrieve customer's address via webservice

Tags: web-services, return, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to retrieve my customer addresses.

This is the code I have for returning the customer data:

`$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => 'http://example.com/api/customers/104'));
$resources = $xml->children()->children();`

And this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
    <id><![CDATA[104]]></id>
    <id_default_group xlink:href="http://example.com/api/groups/3"><![CDATA[3]]></id_default_group>
    <id_lang xlink:href="http://example.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[2]]></id_lang>
    <newsletter_date_add><![CDATA[2016-01-31 23:32:17]]></newsletter_date_add>
    <ip_registration_newsletter><![CDATA[46.245.17.126]]></ip_registration_newsletter>
    <last_passwd_gen><![CDATA[2016-01-31 17:32:17]]></last_passwd_gen>
    <secure_key><![CDATA[15423d30bac893c43344749c515c45f7]]></secure_key>
    <deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
    <passwd><![CDATA[02b5555e9ca7c2ea3588dae0a5e1d950]]></passwd>
    <lastname><![CDATA[Ø§ØµØ§Ù„ØªÛŒ]]></lastname>
    <firstname><![CDATA[Ø¬Ø§ÙˆÛŒØ¯]]></firstname>
    <email><![CDATA[javidasalat@yahoo.com]]></email>
    <id_gender><![CDATA[0]]></id_gender>
    <birthday><![CDATA[1981-08-11]]></birthday>
    <newsletter><![CDATA[1]]></newsletter>
    <optin><![CDATA[0]]></optin>
    <website></website>
    <company><![CDATA[1376709392]]></company>
    <siret></siret>
    <ape></ape>
    <outstanding_allow_amount><![CDATA[0.000000]]></outstanding_allow_amount>
    <show_public_prices><![CDATA[0]]></show_public_prices>
    <id_risk><![CDATA[0]]></id_risk>
    <max_payment_days><![CDATA[0]]></max_payment_days>
    <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    <note></note>
    <is_guest><![CDATA[0]]></is_guest>
    <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
    <id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2016-01-31 23:32:17]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2016-01-31 23:54:54]]></date_upd>
<associations>
<groups nodeType="group" api="groups">

</groups>
</associations>
</customer>
```

It doesn't return the addresses.

> How can I return customer address via webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Because in PrestaShop you should have more of one address you have to retrieve this addresses in two steps.
The first you have to retrieve the customer id (I see, and I suppose that you already have in your case) and then the addresses associated to that customer.

If you want to retrieve via url you have to use the 'filter' function:
`http://example.com/api/addresses/?filter[id_customer]=[104]&filter[deleted]=[0]`
We have two parameters, id_customer that is the id of your customer and the deleted to retrieve only the active addresses

Otherwise you should use the `$opt` array:

```
$opt = array(
    'resource'          =>'addresses',
    'filter[id_customer]' => '[104]',
    'filter[deleted]'  => '[0]'
);
```

After of that you have the list of all the addresses (of that customer), with a `foreach` you can get the addresses id(s) and retrieve all the informations of that address.